# Create BCP Format File From SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulk-insert

I want to create a BCP format file from within SSMS. Is there anyway to do this? All the sources are asking to use the BCP command line. I would rather utilize in SSMS window.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Is there any special reason that you would rather utilize SSMS window to generate BCP format file? I am asking because in theory, you can use xp_cmdshell inside SSMS to create the BCP format file using the example listed in your link

Comment: ah, just preference, I don't like opening two windows another for command prompt, if possible just wondering, if there is no solution,that's fine, will use command prompt Thanks-

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367555/creating-bcp-format-file-for-sql-server-2005